# Cannot invoke "java.io.Console.readLine()" because "c" is null

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, console, system.in

I am trying to get the input from user by using `System.console`. However, I get a `NullPointerException` when I run the following code (I am trying to get input from the user).

```
import java.io.*;
public class Systemlearn {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        Console c=System.console();
        System.out.println("Enter the Name:");
        String str=c.readLine();
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Enter the Name:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.Console.readLine()" because "c" is null
    at week5.Systemlearn.main(Systemlearn.java:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this from an IDE? If yes then that is the problem since `System.console()` is not available in an IDE environment.

Try running it from the console (Command Prompt / Terminal) and it should work fine.

Edit: Just tried in my console and it worked (see screenshot below)

[image: Screenshot]